# Recover deleted build from azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

My build has got deleted from Azure devops as per retention policy. is there a possibility to recover the build.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a possibility to recover the build.

I am afraid you could not recover the build, which deleted by the retention policy.

AFAIK, deletion is generally divided into soft deletion and hard deletion. When we accidentally delete a build, it will be a soft delete and the source data will be kept on the server for a while. However, if the server deletes the build by some policy, then this is a hard delete. The source data will be completely deleted from the server, which is irreversible.

You can try modifying your retention policy to prevent this from happening again.